# How to underscore.js create a group

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

```
{
    "Name": "User1",        
    "SlotStartDate": "05/16/2018",
    "SlotStartTime": "9:20AM"        
},
{
    "Name": "User1",   
    "SlotStartDate": "05/16/2018",
    "SlotStartTime": "10:20AM"
},
{
    "Name": "User1",        
    "SlotStartDate": "05/17/2018",
    "SlotStartTime": "9:20AM"        
},
{
    "Name": "User1",        
    "SlotStartDate": "05/17/2018",
    "SlotStartTime": "10:20AM"        
},
{
    "Name": "User2",
    "SlotStartDate": "05/16/2018",
    "SlotStartTime": "8:45AM"
},
{
    "Name": "User2",
    "SlotStartDate": "05/16/2018",
    "SlotStartTime": "9:25AM"
}
{
    "Name": "User2",
    "SlotStartDate": "05/17/2018",
    "SlotStartTime": "8:45AM"
},
{
    "Name": "User2",
    "SlotStartDate": "05/17/2018",
    "SlotStartTime": "9:25AM"
}
```

How do I use underscore.js to group the data and return an array in following manner:

Group by user and date.

```
User1
- "05/16/2018"
    - "9:20AM"
    - "10:20AM"
- "05/17/2018"
    - "9:20AM"
    - "10:20AM"     
User2
- "05/16/2018"
    - "8:45AM"
    - "9:25AM"
- "05/17/2018"
    - "8:45AM"
    - "9:25AM"
```

I have tried combination for following code:

```
var createGroups = _.groupBy(response2, function(value){
    return  value.Name + '#' + value.SlotStartDate  
});

var groupedData = _.map(createGroups,function(createGroup){
    return {                            
        slottimes: _.pluck(createGroup,'SlotStartTime')
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: an array grouped by user, date and time {User1: {"05/16/2018": "9:20AM","10:20AM"}, {"05/17/2018":"9:20AM","10:20AM"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var groupedData = _.mapObject(_.groupBy(data, 'Name'), (user) => {
  return _.mapObject(_.groupBy(user, 'SlotStartDate'), (date) => {
    return _.pluck(date, 'SlotStartTime');
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/h3mx8qk2/)

Comment: Thanks Riddhesh! Worked perfectly.